# Selenium not Finding Xpath Button element on Twitter

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, bots

```py
Nextbut=self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[6]')
Nextbut.click()
```

This is the path I am using to find the button on twitters website but selenium always returns this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[6]"}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is their another way to select the button element for selenium to click on? Does twitter have a way of making their html unfindable to selenium? P.S. it is also not as simple as selecting the class or span I have tried those and the same issue arises....

I have gotten this to work so I am confused. If I do the same thing with the Nextbut it still doesn't work with the correct Xpath.

```py
email = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="layers"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')
self.action.move_to_element(email).click().perform()
email.send_keys("blabla@gmail.com")
```

Here is full code for problem doesn't seem to want to work to find said element but when I do python -i main.py and do it interactively it finds the element.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time
import Secret

class TwitterBot:

    def __int__(self):

        op = ChromeOptions()
        op.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=op)
        self.driver.get('https://twitter.com')
        self.action = ActionChains(self.driver)
    def login(self):

        log1 = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[5]/a/div')
        log1.click()
        time.sleep(10)
        email = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="layers"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')
        self.action.move_to_element(email).click().perform()
        email.send_keys(Secret.email)
        time.sleep(10)
        Nextbut = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div')
        Nextbut.click()


a = TwitterBot()
a.__int__()
time.sleep(5)
a.login()
```

Comment: How did you get that xpath value?

Comment: Just F12 developer console then right click hit inspect find the html corresponding to the button. Right Click copy the XPath value. All I'm trying to do is click the next button on the page but throws an error saying it doesn't exist. I have gotten the email with sendKeys() method to work but not a simple click.

Answer (score 0):

next button is dynamic in twitter web page u can't use xpath.
use position indexing method to  get the element.
ex: //div[@role='button'][2] for twitter.